# Time picker with UltraMaskedEdit (hh:MM tt) changes format to HH:MM when entering into edit mode

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, timepicker

I am using UltraMaskedEdit control of Infragistics to pick and show Time only in the format : hh:MM tt. It shows up fine normally, but when entering into edit mode it changes its format to HH:MM and here is the problem since I dont want to change the format in edit mode. I am using properties for UltraMaskedEdit Control:

```
UltraMaskedEdit1.EditAs=Infragistics.Win.UltraWinMaskedEdit.EditAsType.DateTime;
UltraMaskedEdit1.InputMask = "{time}";
UltraMaskedEdit1.FormatString = "hh:MM tt";
UltraMaskedEdit1.PromptChar = ' ';
UltraMaskedEdit1.SpinButtonDisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.SpinButtonDisplayStyle.OnRight;
UltraMaskedEdit1.SpinWrap = true;
```

Please let me know if there is any way to achieve this.

Comment: I am still looking for the solution. At least Please let me know if there is no solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the FormatString to "hh:MM tt" will show hours, month and AM/PM. Is this what you really need?
If you need to show hours, minutes and AM/PM setting of InputMask to {time} should be enough. Therefore try to remove the FormatString.